# Programmatic way to switch apps?

Tags: lightning-apps

Is there any programmatic way - Apex, Lightning, URL, etc - to switch a user from being in one Lightning App to another? E.g. the equivalent of the user clicking the upper-left dots menu, choosing something in App Launcher, and ending up in that app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some debugging using lightning inspector and found out what event is fired when we click on a app in app launcher.

So event fired is **force:switchApp** with parameters

```
    var appEvent = $A.get("e.force:switchApp");
    appEvent.setParams({
        "tabsetId": "02uU0000000DtzAIAS",
        "startUrl": "/one/one.app#/sObject/02uU0000000DtzAIAS"
    });
    appEvent.fire();
```

One thing I was not able to find out how to get tabsetid. TabsetId is of sobjectType TabSet.
But TabSet cannot be queried. :( 
I queried appDefination and tabDefination but no luck there also. So only way to find tabsetId is using lightning inspector and then go to event log and find app id.

**Edit**

As suggested by Charles in comments we can use tooling api to get app id using

```
SELECT AppId, Label, Active, SortOrder FROM MenuItem WHERE MenuType = 'AppSwitcher'
```

Comment: That's a good find Manjot. :)

Just a caveat, e.force:switchApp is not documented and might just stop working without notice. I have happened before so should not be relied on as a concrete solution,

Comment: Yes, agree don't use this solution until absolutely necessary or sales force comes with documented solution

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Possible workaround to obtain the app ID programmatically. Create a permission set and assign it only one thing: The one app you want to switch to. Now you can query `SetupEntityAccess` and you will see a record with `SetupEntityType = TabSet`, and `SetupEntityId` starting with `02u`.

Comment: Also you can query these `02u` IDs via Tooling API as such: `SELECT AppId, Label, Active, SortOrder FROM MenuItem WHERE MenuType = 'AppSwitcher'`. Try in Developer Console with the Use Tooling API box checked.

Comment: I guess this could be a whole other question, but did you find any way to detect which Lightning app a component is running in?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone finds this and doesn't know about recent developments: you can navigate to Salesforce apps using Page References with [aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) and [lwc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_page_reference_type) with the `lightning/navigation` component.

You can also just navigate to a url e.g. https://myInstance.lightning.force.com/lightning/app/c__MyCustomApp or  https://myInstance.lightning.force.com/lightning/app/standard__LightningSales.