# Programmatic way to switch current selected app?

Tags: app, switch

This is exactly the same question from here: [Programmatic way to switch apps?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237616/programmatic-way-to-switch-apps)

However this solution is outdated and not working anymore. Is there any way to switch from the current selected app to another one using Lightning or APEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can redirect to the url "/lightning/app/06m2E000000qgp1QAA". The last part is the id of the desired app.

Check the lightning/navigation that can be used both in aura/lwc

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_page_reference_type

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Willian Matheus. But I'm struggling to get the App's ID. How to get that?

Comment: Hi @JulioDidierMaciel try to do a query like these "Select DurableId, Label, MasterLabel, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName from AppDefinition", the DurableId is the one that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out one example to navigate to a record into another app:

URL:

```
/lightning/app/06m1D000000cxIzQAI/r/WorkOrder/0WO1D000000IkrbWAC/view
```

to get current App ID use:

```
String appId = [SELECT Id, AppDefinitionId FROM UserAppInfo WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1].AppDefinitionId;
```